# Redefine any environment and command to an empty output

Tags: compiling, etoolbox

I have defined a few complicated environments and commands. Sometimes I need to to only see the superstructure of my output PDF. For this I need a way to do dry-run. I use a `\toggletrue{dryrun}`  which inputs a file `\input{dryurn}`.

In `dryrun.tex`, my plan is to redefine those complicated commands/environments to produce empty output using the package `savesym`

The command is easily redefined to an empty command. How do I redefine the environment to an empty body.

This is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{savesym,etoolbox}

% these definition go into a separate file
\newenvironment{myenv}{
    \noindent\textbf{Preamble}\hfill\\% % Preamble stands for something much more complicated
} {%
    \newline\textbf{Epilogue}% % epilogue also stands for more complicated commands
}
\newcommand{\mycmd}{\textbf{COMPLICATED COMMAND}}

\newtoggle{dryrun}
\togglefalse{dryrun}
\toggletrue{dryrun}

% the following are contents of dryrun.tex
\iftoggle{dryrun} {
    \savesymbol{myenv}
    \savesymbol{endmyenv}
    \renewcommand{\mycmd}{\,}
    \newenvironment{myenv}{
        \origmyenv
    }{
        \origendmyenv
    }% should be empty, but still produce the preamble and epilogue
}

\begin{document}

Environment = 

\begin{myenv} 
    This line should be only in a normal run
\end{myenv} % does not work as intended for the dry-run

Command = \mycmd % works correctly for dry-run

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `verbatim` package for this:

```
\usepackage{verbatim}
\let\myenv=\comment
\let\endmyenv=\endcomment
```

Of course, this ends up just throwing away the contents. If you want to include the preamble and epilogue, you would have to look at the definition of the `comment` environment from `verbatim` and edit it slightly:

```
\def\myenv{\noindent\textbf{Preamble}\hfill\\
 \@bsphack
 \let\do\@makeother\dospecials\catcode‘\^^M\active
 \let\verbatim@startline\relax
 \let\verbatim@addtoline\@gobble
 \let\verbatim@processline\relax
 \let\verbatim@finish\relax
 \verbatim@}
\def\endmyenv{\newline\textbf{Epilouge}\@esphack}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that mess with the Prolouge and Epilouge of ``myenv``?

Comment: Ahh, in that case you need to do a little bit more. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: This will work with the minimally defined Preamble and Epilouge. In my MWE, they actually stand for much more than just ``\textbf{Preamble}``, including ``enumerate`` lists and a lot of formatting. I want to preserve all that without retyping everything so that the original ``myenv`` can later be open to modification and dryrun still works.

Comment: I would suggest putting the preamble stuff and the epilogue stuff into macros and including them. The rest of the definition of `\myenv` and `\endmyenv` would stay the same.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this simple yet super effective trick!

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer using idea from @Don Hosek.

This preserves all Preamble and Epilogue.

First I preserved the meaning of `myenv` using `savesymbol` directive, then I used an auxiliary command to embed the empty `myenv` which then called a auxillay environment `AUXmyenv`. this auxilary environment is redefined to a comment using `verbatim` package. finally `myenv` is redefined with all this structure.

The Solution in the form of MWE is :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{savesym,etoolbox,verbatim}

% these definition go into a separate file
\newenvironment{myenv}{
    \noindent\textbf{Preamble}\hfill\\%
} {%
    \newline\textbf{Epilouge}%
}
\newcommand{\mycmd}{\textbf{COMPLICATED COMMAND}}

\newtoggle{dryrun}
%\togglefalse{dryrun}
\toggletrue{dryrun}

\makeatletter
% the following are contents of dryrun.tex
\iftoggle{dryrun} {
    \savesymbol{myenv}
    \savesymbol{endmyenv}
    \renewcommand{\mycmd}{\,}
    
    \newcommand{\AUXenv}{
        \origmyenv %
        % optional TEXT
        \origendmyenv %
    }
    
    \newenvironment{AUXmyenv}{}{}
    
    \newenvironment{myenv}{
        \AUXenv
        \AUXmyenv
    }{
        \endAUXmyenv
    }
    
    \let\AUXmyenv=\comment
    \let\endAUXmyenv=\endcomment
    
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Environment = 

\begin{myenv} 
    This line should be only in a normal run
\end{myenv} % does not work as intended for the dry-run


Command = \mycmd % works correctly for dry-run



\end{document}
```